# php function class_exists causes crash in production environment

Tags: php, zend-framework, crash

I'm using the Zend Framework, version 1.10.7 for my application

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $application->bootstrap();
    echo 'ha';
    var_dump(class_exists('Default_Model_FeedReader_Csv_HappyHome'));
    echo 'hoi';
```

The output the this piece of code is only "ha". Error reporting is on, but there are no errors. The script simply stops executing after class_exists is called.

With this code

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo 'ha';
var_dump(class_exists('Default_Model_FeedReader_Csv_HappyHome'));
echo 'hoi';
$application->bootstrap();
```

the output is as expected, "ha bool(false) hoi" (Here the autoloader is not registered because $application->bootstrap() is not yet called).

The problem is that this crash only occurs in production environment and not on my local development machine. Has somebody an idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid question from me. Linux is of course case sensitive and Windows not, that's why a class name could not be found. I have te solution

Answer (score 0):

Just to know, what were the real class and/or file names ?